# swift обновление текущих коодинат yandex map

Tags: swift

получаю и показываю на карте текущее месторасположение :

```
    mapView.mapWindow.map.isRotateGesturesEnabled = false
    mapView.mapWindow.map.move(with:
        YMKCameraPosition(target: YMKPoint(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), zoom: 14, azimuth: 0, tilt: 0))

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    let userLocationLayer = mapView.mapWindow.map.userLocationLayer
    userLocationLayer.isEnabled = true
    userLocationLayer.isHeadingEnabled = true
    userLocationLayer.setAnchorWithAnchorNormal(
        CGPoint(x: 0.5 * mapView.frame.size.width * scale, y: 0.5 * mapView.frame.size.height * scale),
        anchorCourse: CGPoint(x: 0.5 * mapView.frame.size.width * scale, y: 0.83 * mapView.frame.size.height * scale))

    userLocationLayer.setObjectListenerWith(self)


    func onObjectAdded(with view: YMKUserLocationView) {
    view.arrow.setIconWith(UIImage(named:"userArrow")!)

    let pinPlacemark = view.pin.useCompositeIcon()

    pinPlacemark.setIconWithName("icon",
                                 image: UIImage(named:"Icon")!,
                                 style:YMKIconStyle(
                                    anchor: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) as NSValue,
                                    rotationType:YMKRotationType.rotate.rawValue as NSNumber,
                                    zIndex: 0,
                                    flat: true,
                                    visible: true,
                                    scale: 1.5,
                                    tappableArea: nil))

    pinPlacemark.setIconWithName(
        "pin",
        image: UIImage(named:"SearchResult")!,
        style:YMKIconStyle(
            anchor: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5) as NSValue,
            rotationType:YMKRotationType.rotate.rawValue as NSNumber,
            zIndex: 1,
            flat: true,
            visible: true,
            scale: 1,
            tappableArea: nil))

    view.accuracyCircle.fillColor = UIColor.blue
}

func onObjectRemoved(with view: YMKUserLocationView) {}

func onObjectUpdated(with view: YMKUserLocationView, event: YMKObjectEvent) {

}
```

проблема в том, что идет постоянное обновление и камера перекидывает на текущее расположение (если сместиться на карте в другое место). Как можно показать текущее расположение на карте и узнать координаты, но без постоянного обновления ?

Answer (score 0):

Вначале получаете координаты через слой:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: YMKMapView!
    let userLocationLayer = mapView.mapWindow.map.userLocationLayer
    userLocationLayer.isEnabled = true
```

Затем отключаете обновление:

```
    userLocationLayer.isEnabled = false
```